# Breaking out time card data into minutes and pivot. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have some time card data that i am trying to calculate the minutes working each hour and pivot the data.

A Picture is probably easier than trying to explain.

[image: Picture]

The highlighted is a a example of 7/1/20. The left table is what i am seeing in the SQL Server table, which is called TimeCard. The right table is what im trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sample data as text, preferably DDL and DML statements, is far better received than images.

Comment: Sample output does not correlate to the SQL data. Ex. Employee # 100006 on 7/1 worked 12 hours and 19 minutes... Your output shows 15 hours 41 minutes... Also, is the lunch and breaks paid for?

Comment: J-m, do you try query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use also use `CASE` instead of `PIVOT` and `operator cross apply` with table *master.dbo.spt_values* to get list of hours between Punch_In_time and Punch_out_time.Then get minutes for each time.

In query please replace aliases with your columns name and table name.

```
select EmployeeId,
max(CASE WHEN number=4 then min else 0 end) AS '4 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=5 then min else 0 end) AS '5 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=6 then min else 0 end) AS '6 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=7 then min else 0 end) AS '7 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=8 then min else 0 end) AS '8 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=9 then min else 0 end) AS '9 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=10 then min else 0 end) AS '10 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=11 then min else 0 end) AS '11 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=12 then min else 0 end) AS '12 AM',
max(CASE WHEN number=13 then min else 0 end) AS '1 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=14 then min else 0 end) AS '2 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=15 then min else 0 end) AS '3 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=16 then min else 0 end) AS '4 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=17 then min else 0 end) AS '5 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=18 then min else 0 end) AS '6 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=19 then min else 0 end) AS '7 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=20 then min else 0 end) AS '8 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=21 then min else 0 end) AS '9 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=22 then min else 0 end) AS '10 PM',
max(CASE WHEN number=23 then min else 0 end) AS '11 PM'
    from
   (
   select X.*,P.number,
    case when datepart(hh,Punch_In_time)=number then 
    IIF(datepart(minute,Punch_In_time)=0,60,datepart(minute,Punch_In_time))
      when datepart(hh,Punch_Out_time)=number then 
    IIF(datepart(minute,Punch_Out_time)=0,60,datepart(minute,Punch_Out_time))
      else 60
    end min
    from 
     (select * from Table where Punch_in_date='7/1/2020')X
    cross apply
    master.dbo.spt_values P
    where P.type='P' And P.number>=datepart(hh,Punch_In_time) and  P.number<=datepart(hh,Punch_Out_time)
   )Y
    group by EmployeeId
```

Comment: I ran the query. It looks like a good starting point for me. I will need to tweak some things and add more hours and possibly incorporate more days into the query.